# How to stop timer

Tags: android, timer

Hi I have a button and a timer

I want to run a timer but when I click a button the timer should stop and the method `test()` should be called.

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button button;
int a=1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            a=6;
        }
    });
    new CountDownTimer(30000, 4000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            if (a<5)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+a, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
           test();
        }
    }.start();
}
private void test ()
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "test is run", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to define it first:

```
 CountDownTimer yourCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 4000) {                     

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

           if (a<5)
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+a, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            test();
        }
    }.start();

yourCountDownTimer.cancel(); //To Stop Timer
```

Comment: `stop()` sure??

Comment: Sorry my mistake, fixed now :)

Answer (score 1):

**using cancel key word**

```
timer.cancel();
    timer.purge();
```

Comment: where is purge();

Comment: thts also using cancel tht timer

Comment: but there is no such method in CountDownTimer class.

Comment: fin brother i think its deprecated

Comment: Timer and CountDownTimer are two different classes. One is of Java and another one is of Andorid. Timer class having purge() method.

Comment: thats rit brother thank you. but handler also this same concept.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136610/discussion-between-akash-and-abhishek-aryan).

Answer (score 1):

```
private CountDownTimer timer;

timer=new CountDownTimer(30000, 4000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            if (a<5)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+a, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
           test();
        }
    }.start();
```

call `timer.cancel()` on `onClick()` metod of your button Listener.